# How should I simulate this Markov Decision Process?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, deep-rl, open-ai

I am working on solving a problem on nodes in a graph communicating with each other. They try to estimate a central state using Kalman consensus filter, with the connections described by the graph's adjacency matrix. Considering time to be discrete, the adjacency matrix changes at each time instant with a transition probability matrix (unknown) to some other matrix (in some finite set of matrices). I want to simulate this in python to solve an MDP with some cost/reward function. (An external agent is concerned with this cost/reward and takes actions accordingly)

Since the state space can be large, my advisor suggested using deep-RL techniques. However I have only studied (formally) basic RL (Q learning, stochastic approximation, etc. with finite states and finite actions at every instant). I tried looking at RL libraries but I can't figure out which one to pick. And even before that I am very confused by how to simulate KCF between nodes in python (from scratch?). How should I proceed?